# ListBox not scrolling on IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, listbox

I have a ListBox which only becomes scrollable on Internet Explorer when Enabled="true". Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail? Perhaps some example code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could style it so it *looks* disabled but isn't really and add a client handler to ignore keypress / mouseclick.

Just make sure you don't treat it as an enabled control on the server side. You could easily bypass that on the client.